# To change JavaScript into jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to be able to make a regular javascript/html element, but I need to find out how to `change document.getElementById()` into `$()`. How can I change `document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;` into jQuery?
All replies would be useful.

Comment: Seriously? Did you try this at all yourself?

Comment: I don't know jquery..i am new in it..learning now..just started

Comment: Why is my question voted down?? cant i ask what i don't know??

Comment: likely down-voted because this is not difficult to research by simply going to the jQuery API, or even a web search

Comment: Although, I don't see anything wrong with the question, but as others have cited it is dead simple to search for the answer. In [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=innerhtml+jquery), keywords `innerhtml jquery` points to JQuery documentation at top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with .html()

```
$("#response").html(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this `.html`

```
  $('#response').html(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function of jQuery. As for the selector you have to put a [`#` in front of the id](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to mark it as such.

```
$( '#response' ).html( res );
```